# Text send via Bluetooth is broken up by first character on the receiving end?

Tags: java, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth, hc-05

I programmed a Bluetooth messaging app, the app works correctly when it connects and pairs with another phone, but when with HC-05 it connects, I get the received message as a syllable (first letter and then the rest of the letters) so what is the reason for that?

[Screenshot My Android App of BTChat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kU3g.jpg)

this my code :

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
    mmSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;
    OutputStream tmpOut = null;
    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    mmInStream = tmpIn;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    mState = STATE_CONNECTED;
}

public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            //***NEW Edition
            String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionLost();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

- packet data transmition by BT protocol. If slave have buffered only one char and master make transmit request than slave send only one char
- multitasking in android OS. Your `run` function not run whole time. There is many threads and proccesses which compete for hw cores. During `run` is suspended many packets can arrive.

You must count that stream not deliver data continously